# Mostrar usuários online

Tags: php, sql

Bom pessoal estou querendo fazer um sistema onde mostra os usuários online no momento porem os mesmos são exibidos mais sem restrições, alguém me da uma luz

```
$timestamp=time(); 
$timeout=time()-300;    
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE novo_usuarios SET timestamp='$timestamp' WHERE ID='$id_user'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM novo_usuarios WHERE timestamp<$timeout ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

aqui vai o echo

Comment: Os utilizadores tem que estar autenticados para aparecer, certo?

Comment: sim , no site so ira visualizar o conteudo os usuarios logados

Comment: então, cria uma tabela com o id de utilizador e o estado. Cada vez que o utilizador entrar, o estado muda. Para ver que está logado, basta fazer uma consulta a essa tabela

Comment: sim isso eu sei fazer , mais nessa questao acime em si qual o problema? teoricamente era para listar somente os que que o timestamp e menor do que 5 minutos estou certo? quero saber o pq não esta listando OBS: o update esta funcionando perfeito , grava no campo o time, o que ta pegando e que na hora de exibir ele ta exibindo tudo como se nao tivesse a condição do WHERE

Comment: Verifica esta linha, faltam as peliculas
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM novo_usuarios WHERE timestamp < '$timeout'");

Comment: Realmente tambem não era isso acrecentei e continua do mesmo jeito

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta usar as funções de tempo do próprio mysql. Não precisa nem calcular o tempo em PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE novo_usuario SET validade=ADDTIME(NOW(),'0:05:00') WHERE ID=$id_user");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM novo_usuario WHERE validade>NOW()");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
...
```

Lembre-se de usar uma coluna do tipo `datetime` (ou até `timestamp`) para armazenar a hora. Sugiro não usar *timestamp* como nome de campo, para não confundir com a palavra reservada `timestamp`.

Explicação da solução:

- na 1<sup>a</sup> query, atualizamos o campo `validade` do usuário corrente com a data e hora somadas a 5 minutos, usando as funções NOW() e ADDTIME() do próprio MySQL (NOW()pode ser substituída pela variável interna CURRENT_TIMESTAMP se preferir).
- na 2<sup>a</sup> query, nós comparamos o campo `validade` com o momento atual. Se ainda não passaram esses 5 minutos, a comparação será verdadeira, e o usuário em questão incluído nos resultados.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que isso resolva apenas o que você precisa, não o problema em si.

```
$timestamp=time(); 
$timeout=time()-300; 
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE novo_usuarios SET timestamp='$timestamp' WHERE ID='$id_user'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM novo_usuarios WHERE ".intval(timestamp)." < ".intval($timeout));
```